# SQL query does not return value when using FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER

Tags: sql, json, asp.net-core

I'm using Dapper in my ASP.NET Core project to return data from the database.

However, I would like to return the data without the `[].`  I've tried using `FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` but whenever I do, the query does not return any values. It does however return values when I try it in SQL Server. There, I get a result as:

```
{"retailerID":-1,"author":"sa","text":"new note 4","dateCreated":"2021-07-30T11:30:00.983","id":3671}
```

But, when I add `FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` in my ASP code, and try it in postman, the output is (in postman i added the same id (3671)):

```
[{"retailerID":0,"author":"","text":"","dateCreated":"1753-01-01T00:00:00","id":0}]
```

Here's the ASP method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<RequestInternalNotes>> getInternalNotes (RequestInternalNotes model)
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@id", model.id);

    var getInternalNote = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<RequestInternalNotes>($@"SELECT TOP 1
            RetailerNote.RetailerID as retailerID, 
            CreatedBy as author, RetailerNote.Name as text, 
            RetailerNote.CreatedDate as dateCreated, RetailerNote.ID as id
            FROM
                [dbo].[RetailerNote] 
            WHERE 
                RetailerNote.ID = @id
            FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER", parameters);

    return getInternalNote;
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> getInternalNotes([FromQuery] RequestInternalNotes model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    try
    {
        var list = await _request.getInternalNotes(model);
        return Ok(list);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

If I delete the `FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`, postman returns the values. Anyone know why this is happening?

**Update**: I figured maybe the problem was that I am using a model for my values, and this creates some error when *`FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`* creates a single object of the query? Here's my model:

```
public class RequestInternalNotes
{
    public int retailerID { get; set; } = 0;
    public string author { get; set; } = "";
    public string text { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Parse("1753-01-01");
    public int id { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

I've also tried the following:

```
var list = await _request.getInternalNotes(model);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
return Ok(json);
```

But I'm still not able to use the `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` without losing the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the answer was not that complicated, adding `SingleOrDefault` in the controller fixed it. Here's the code, in case anyone else comes across this problem!

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> getInternalNotes([FromQuery] RequestInternalNotes model)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            try
            {
                var list = await _request.getInternalNotes(model);
                return Ok(list.SingleOrDefault());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```